# Elasticsearch get only file ids

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way in elasticsearch using JAVA API to get only the ids of the documents returned for a give query.

```
SearchResponse sr =  esClient.prepareSearch(index).setSize(resultSize).setScroll(new TimeValue(10000)).setQuery(fqb).setFetchSource(false).get();
```

but I get empty hits (`sr.getHits().hits[].length == 0`) althouh the total count of returned hits is 0 (`sr.getHits().getTotalHits == 2`). I understand that nothing is returned by elasticsearch because I set fetch source to false, but the ids should somehow be available. My current solution is:

```
SearchResponse sr =  esClient.prepareSearch(index).setSize(resultSize).setScroll(new TimeValue(10000)).setQuery(fqb).srb.setFetchSource("_id", null).get();
```

However I think that gets the _id field from source, and for speed I would like to avoid this if possible.

Thanks,
Ilija

Answer (score 0):

add `.addField("_id")` to your search

```
SearchResponse sr = esClient.prepareSearch(index)
                .setSize(resultSize)
                .setScroll(new TimeValue(10000))
                .setQuery(fqb)
                .setFetchSource(false)
                .addField("_id")
                .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me (elasticsearch 5.4):

```
esClient.getClient()
  .prepareSearch(INCIDENT_INDEX_NAME)
  .setTypes(INCIDENT_DOCUMENT_TYPE)
  .setSize(1000)
  .setFetchSource(false)
  .get()

Set<String> ids = new HashSet<>();
    response.getHits().forEach(hit -> ids.add(hit.getId()));
```